# Comparing two observable arrays gives null inspite of differing elements

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to compare two observable arrays.
But the ko.utils.compareArrays is not able to provide me with the differing elements between two observable arrays.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8fq57q9)

```
var ViewModel = function() {
 var self = this;
 self.y= ko.observableArray(["", "a","b","e","d"]);
 self.x = ko.observableArray(["a","b","e"]);

self.differ=ko.utils.compareArrays(x,y);   

}
```

Am I missing out on somethig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `ko.utils.compareArrays(self.x(),self.y())`

x and y aren't declared. Only self.x and self.y are. Also they are observable arrays so you need to evaluate them i.e. `self.x()`

After that then you will notice that the differences are structured in objects with status property containing what differs and value containing the value. To only show the items added you can use an if in your view.:

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
   <ul data-bind="foreach:differ">
       <!-- ko if: status == 'added' -->
       <li data-bind="text:'\'' + value + '\''"></li>
       <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

This js fiddle will show the added items: http://jsfiddle.net/L8fq57q9/5/

Comment: Thanks Wayne. My bad I updated it wrongly. New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8fq57q9/) . As you can see I am not able to get the differing elements between the arrays.

Comment: So when it shows object it means that the differences are in objects. The easy way to find out is to right it to the console in the browser. http://jsfiddle.net/L8fq57q9/2/ Then in your browser bring up the developer tools and you can see the structure of the objects. You then can adjust your view accordingly

Comment: I see that the differing elements have a status of added. So all differing elements will have a status of 'Added'? If so, we could filter out the elements with 'Added' status.

Comment: Yes I got that. I really do not find enough knockout array functions api documentation online that makes it really tough to track through. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Knockmeout has some documentation: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html